# Do we need to create tables for the @Embedded items in the entities in Room Database?

Tags: java, android, database, android-room

I have an entity named as "config", inside this I have a primary key and a list of another entity embedded into this using @Embedded annotation.

```
@Entity(tableName = "config")
public class ConfigModules {

@PrimaryKey
@ColumnInfo(name = "id")
private Long id;

@JsonProperty("modules")
@Embedded
private ArrayList<ConfigModuleEntity> modules;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public ArrayList<ConfigModuleEntity> getModules() {
    return modules;
}

public void setModules(ArrayList<ConfigModuleEntity> modules) {
    this.modules = modules;
}}
```

And the above embedded annotation ConfigModuleEntity is as specified below:

```
@Entity(tableName = "config_module")
public class ConfigModuleEntity {

@JsonProperty("id")
@ColumnInfo(name = "module_id")
private String moduleId;

@JsonProperty("isConfigSupported")
@ColumnInfo(name = "isConfigSupported")
private int isConfigSupported;

@JsonProperty("subModules")
@Embedded
private ArrayList<ConfigSubModuleEntity> subModules;

public String getModuleId() {
    return moduleId;
}

public void setModuleId(String moduleId) {
    this.moduleId = moduleId;
}

public int getIsConfigSupported() {
    return isConfigSupported;
}

public void setIsConfigSupported(int isConfigSupported) {
    this.isConfigSupported = isConfigSupported;
}

public ArrayList<ConfigSubModuleEntity> getSubModules() {
    return subModules;
}

public void setSubModules(ArrayList<ConfigSubModuleEntity> subModules) {
    this.subModules = subModules;
}}
```

So, while creating the table, we need to specify just the parent entity and room database will create the child tables automatically, or we need to create tables for each entity?

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood what the `@Embedded` annotation does.

It doesn't create tables. The `@Entity` annotation does that. 

Instead, it creates columns named from the fields in the embedded class in your table. See here for more https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Embedded

In this case, the generated table `config` will have a column `modules` with the embedded data (I believe you need a type converter because it's a list of custom objects). 

I don't really know what you're trying to achieve, maybe you can explain more?

Comment: @SegunFamisa I am trying to achieve a one to many relationship. I have some array of objects which I want to store it in room db. And query it to fetch the details. I was confused which one to go for. Embedded or with foreignKeys.

Comment: if what you're trying to achieve is one-to-many relationships, then you should probably be looking at this https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/defining-data#object-relationships